# What is O(n^n / n!)

Tags: math, big-o

n^n grows significantly faster than n!, but how much faster? When I eyeball it, the ratio seems to grow exponentially, e.g O(e^n) but I haven’t been able to prove anything yet. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) should help.

Comment: If you consider it as a product of n/i for i = 1 to n, then n/i >= 2 for i <= n/2. Therefore, n^n/n! >= 2^(n/2).

Comment: This should be posted over on the [maths.se] site instead.